# How can I stop my pie from burning?

Tags: baking, oven

My oven heats up by putting on the grill. Yesterday I was making pie and the top burned a little bit. This happens almost every time. It happens at the moment the grill goes on for a short moment because the oven has cooled down a bit. So the top of my pie burns, but the middle is not fully cooked jet. 
I always make sure the oven is fully heated before putting in the pie, and of course keep the oven door open as short as possible. 
I was wondering, is there a trick so that my pie does not get burned when the oven is re-heating? 
Right now I turn down the oven a little bit so it won't re-heat which indeed prevent the pie from burning. However, in this way I do not get the optimal result.

Comment: How is the result not optimal when you bake at a reduced temperature? What is wrong with the pie?

Comment: Well if I bake a pie which need long time, for example over an hour, I have to reduce the temperature for about 4/5 times with 5 Celsius. Which results in a reduced temperature of 25 decrease. This is a reduction of over 10% in most cases, which results in a slightly different cooking time. But if I want to check if it is ready, I have to open the door, which will again result in reduced temperature...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is to deflect the heat from the top of your pie. If you have two racks in your oven, and can position them so that the pie is in the middle with a rack above it, place a piece of aluminum foil directly above the pie. Another option would be to set a piece of foil on top of the pie after it has partially baked. Either way will protect the top from direct heat, allowing the ambient heat to penetrate and bake the whole pie.

Comment: Great minds think alike :D

Comment: I guess this only works with pies and other bakeries without a crunchy crust? For example you want 'soggy' breads. If I want a crunchy crust, should it work by removing the aluminium in the last minutes?

Comment: You can either remove the foil toward the end or wait until it is partially browned before adding it.

Comment: Just use a standard metal cookie/baking sheet on the rack above. Saves wasting Aluminium foil :-)

Comment: The issue with using a sheet pan is that heating one with nothing on it may cause it to warp. At one cent (US) for a square foot or so of aluminum foil, I'm inclined to 'waste' the foil...

Comment: @Lotte : don't tightly cover the pie, you just want it to deflect the radiant heat (which is why TFD's suggestion of a pan on the shelf above works).

Answer (score 4):

Simply cover the the pie with foil once it has browned sufficiently. The foil will protect the pastry while the filling cooks. This is a common method for preventing pie crusts that are blind-baked from over-browning.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried brushing with cold water every 10 mins if some bits of the crust, e.g. edges, are going brown too fast. Seems to work pretty well.